# Pin it button doesn't pop up?

Tags: jquery, pinterest

I implemented pin it button successfully and it works fine, just it does not open in pop up, it's opening new page. I want it open in pop up window.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#i-cell-" + cnt_rows + "-" + cnt_cells+page)
    .append($("<div>")
    .append($("<a href='//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://www.facebook.com/ElmSandBox/app_338950576241266/&media="+encodeURIComponent(items[cnt].item_img)+"&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest' data-pin-do='buttonPin' target='_top' data-pin-config='above' onclick='storePinterest(\""+items[cnt].item_id+"\")'><img src='//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png' /></a>")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `target='_top'` with `target=_blank`.

That will open a new window.

If you want a more traditional popup (i.e. smaller, no navigation bar, etc.), you should use some code similar to this (from [here](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://YOUR URL HERE');">Pin it!</a>
```

Comment: in fact it was opening in same window now after using target=_blank. it is opening in new window but not pop up

Comment: Ok, if you want to make it look like a popup then you should use the code I've provided (or something similar using javascript `window.open()`) as mentioned in the post.

Comment: i think that pin it button can be configured to open as pop up, is there anyway to do it?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything special about your pin it button that would stop you using the code I've provided.

Comment: still one problem, the pop window is not taking the image url correctly